# Show $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{n}-1 \over {\ln{n} \over n}}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How can I show without the use of derivatives that

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{n}-1 \over {\ln{n} \over n}}=1$$
?

Comment: It may be helpful to notice that $$\frac{\ln n}{n} = \frac1n \ln n = \ln\left(n^\frac1n\right) = \ln(\sqrt[n]{n})$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One may use
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{e^x-1 \over x}=1
$$ observing that $\displaystyle \sqrt[n]{n}=e^{\large\frac{\ln n}n}$.

Comment: Nice observation!

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{n}-1 \over {\ln{n} \over n}}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\frac{\ln(\sqrt[n]{n})}{\sqrt[n]{n}-1}}=\frac{1}{\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(\sqrt[n]{n})-\ln 1}{\sqrt[n]{n}-1}}\cdot$$ Since
$$\lim\limits_{x\to1}\frac{\ln x-\ln 1}{x-1}=(\ln x)_{x=1}'=1$$
by changing the variable as $x=\sqrt[n]{n}$ we conclude 
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(\sqrt[n]{n})-\ln 1}{\sqrt[n]{n}-1}=1.$$